# get results for multiple keywords Alchemy Data news Api

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, alchemyapi

Alchemy Data news Api is not providing any results when running multiple keywords.
Whereas runs fine when running on a single keyword.

here is the URL:

```
https://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/data/GetNews?apikey=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE&return=enriched.url.title,enriched.url.url,enriched.url.entities,enriched.url.docSentiment,enriched.url.concepts,enriched.url.taxonomy&start=1457568000&end=1458255600&q.enriched.url.text=apple%20clean%20technology&count=25&outputMode=json
```

result:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "usage": "By accessing AlchemyAPI or using information generated by AlchemyAPI, you are agreeing to be bound by the AlchemyAPI Terms of Use: http://www.alchemyapi.com/company/terms.html",
    "totalTransactions": "191",
    "result": {
        "status": "OK"
    }
}
```

do i need to include any other parameter to get results for multiple keywords.
Is it because I am just using the query builder demo?. And it could be possible programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an "and" search use

```
A[apple^clean^technology]
```

or in context of your example:

```
https://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/data/GetNews?apikey=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE&return=enriched.url.title,enriched.url.url,enriched.url.entities,enriched.url.docSentiment,enriched.url.concepts,enriched.url.taxonomy&start=1457568000&end=1458255600&q.enriched.url.text=A[apple^clean^technology]&count=25&outputMode=json
```

See more in the Parameters (filters) section of the docs [here](https://alchemyapi.readme.io/v1.0/docs/rest-api-documentation#section-parameters-filters-).

I am a Developer Evangelist with IBM Watson.